# Firebase database and google cloud storage out of sync

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I can upload a new object to the google storage bucket, and it will put the object in the database for the firebase project. But when I delete it does not update the google storage bucket -- any tips for how to get to the bottom of this?

Additionally there are a couple thousand objects in the google storage but not in the firebase database. How do I sync these two so the objects in the GS bucket are also in the firebase database

I tried a test and using `gutils rsync` uploaded an image, then deleted it in the firestore and when i tried uploading it again I get

```
Building synchronization state...
At destination listing 10000...
At destination listing 20000...
At destination listing 30000...
At destination listing 40000...
Starting synchronization...
Copying file://./.DS_Store [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
- [1/1 files][  6.0 KiB/  6.0 KiB] 100% Done
```

UPDATE:

I believe it has to do with an issue with 'application/octet-stream' vs `image/jpeg` and deletions -- any advice for how to switch those over to `image/jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

You can write two Cloud Functions triggers, one that responds to changes in your storage bucket (a storage trigger), and another the responds to changes in your database (a Firestore trigger).  If either function detects a change, it can make a corresponding update in the other product.

If you want to perform a one-time synchronization, you will just have to write code to find the differences and make the appropriate changes.  A Cloud Functions trigger would not be the best way to do this.

Comment: Thank you - I do have it set up with cloud functions to update based on events within the firestore. Something is going on with some images being uploaded as application/octet-stream vs image files. Any advice for how to change the objects in the google storage which are currently `application/octet-stream` to turn them into image files?

Comment: That sounds like an unrelated issue.  Please as a new question that describes the specific problem you're running into.